# Throw the same Exception if it is not handled, or construct a new Exception?

Tags: java, exception

Item Number 6 in [this](http://codebuild.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/15-best-practices-about-exception.html) article states:

> Try not to re-throw the exception because of the price. Bu if
>   re-throwing had been a must, re-throw the same exception instead of
>   creating a new exception. This will bring additional performance. You
>   may add additional info in each layer to that exception.

Well but this violates the separation of layers, isn't it?

Let's say I have a specific implementation of DAO which throws an **SQLException**

Let's say my Service Layer (or Business Layer..) calls a method from the DAO Layer, but decides not to handle the Exception thrown.

If I re-throw the SQLException to the View Layer, my View Layer will not only be coupled to the DAO Layer, isn't it?

Isn't it right to throw a new Exception, so that View is dependent **only** on layer one level below, and not two?

What advantages does throwing the same Exception bring, except performance?

Comment: Depends on how you catch it.  If you just catch Throwable at the top-layer and print a stack trace and the message then you are not violating anything (your top level only depends on Throwable).  If you catch the DAO specific exception then something fishy is going on.

Comment: Yes, that is silly advice. If you need to rethrow, throw something that is semantically meaningful for that level of the api, your take on it sounds completely reasonable

Comment: I can't imagine that the performance hit of creating and throwing a new exception instead of the same one is meaningful in any realistic way.

Comment: @Pace it does not depend on how you catch it. It depends on whether the abstraction your call is exposing (say, a view) can sensibly and meaningfully expose something like a low-level persistence exception. Should a view client have to know about SQLExceptions? that's what matters

Comment: If you read the comments in the article, the #6 is the most contested. Most people would not suggest re-throwing the same exception unless there's some strong reason.

Comment: I would be careful when reading that blog. Giving a set of 15 best practices without much of a reasoning behind them indicates poor quality. Some of the practices are well known and accepted, but some are unclear and questionable, making me wonder if you should rely on the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I re-throw the `SQLException` to the View Layer, my View Layer will not only be coupled to the DAO Layer, isn't it?

This is absolutely correct.

> Isn't it right to throw a new Exception, so that View is dependent only on layer one level below, and not two?

Absolutely. If your DAO layer cannot handle the exception coming from SQL, it should catch it, make as much sense of it as possible, and throw its own exception.

Consider an example: let's say your DAO layer allows you to add new items where a certain attribute must be unique. SQL layer may have a unique constraint or a unique index to enforce this constraint on RDBMS layer. If the caller of your DAO layer attempt saving an object that violates the uniqueness constraint, SQL exception would be thrown. If you let this exception propagate to callers, chances are that they would have no idea of what to do with it, and perhaps even show it to end-users:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (UxPatient_rec_soc) violated

This solution is very bad, but an alternative to try and make sense of it on the client is even more fragile.

Your DAO should catch the exception, decide what it means for the caller, and throw its own exception. This way you would be able to change your implementation independently of your caller.

**General note:** Performance considerations should be among the least important when deciding on throwing / re-throwing an exception, because exceptions should be thrown only in rare exceptional situations. Clarity of your interfaces is a lot more important.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you on that throwing a more descriptive exception towards your layer wrapping the original one would be more convenient. The SQLException in this case might be a low-level issue which can be interpreted and put into business context by throwing a new more descriptive exception.

Also please consider that usually the performance of error handling itself is not something you'd like to optimize for. So it's true that throwing an exception is slower compared to returning from the method, but this happens only when something goes wrong. (Because you should avoid using exceptions for handling normal program flows)

I don't see any advantage in throwing the same exception, unless you really can't add any information by wrapping it. In that case don't do that.